# How to set edittext to show search button or enter button on keyboard?

Tags: android, keyboard

How to set `EditText` to show Search button or enter button on keyboard?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Use the code to edit EditText attribute

```
<EditText android:imeOptions="actionSearch" />
```

Then do this in your java code:

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
            performSearch();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Works fine. 
Called api on Search action.

Answer (score 221):

In your layout set input method to option to Search

```
 <EditText 
  android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
  android:inputType="text"/>
```

and in java code use

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
            performSearch();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: I had to set `android:inputType="text"` for my edittext to make this work

Comment: yes you need to add `android:inputType="text"` for higher API levels. (For ICS+ I think)

Comment: Keep in mind if a user is using an external keyboard they probably won't have a search button. If you don't have another way of performing the search you may also want to check for `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER`

Comment: You should make KeyEvent optional in Kotlin, if not this code will cause a crash.
Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47849219/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-parameter-specified-as-non-null-is-null-me

Answer (score 18):

```
  android:singleLine="true"
  android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
```

Answer (score 3):

The following procedure describes how to set up an AutoCompleteTextView that provides suggestions from an array, using ArrayAdapter:

**1 -** Add the AutoCompleteTextView to your layout. Here's a layout with only the text field:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AutoCompleteTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/autocomplete_country"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**2 -** Define the array that contains all text suggestions. For example, here's an array of country names that's defined in an XML resource file (res/values/strings.xml):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="countries_array">
        <item>Afghanistan</item>
        <item>Albania</item>
        <item>Algeria</item>
        <item>American Samoa</item>
        <item>Andorra</item>
        <item>Angola</item>
        <item>Anguilla</item>
        <item>Antarctica</item>
        ...
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

**3 -** In your Activity or Fragment, use the following code to specify the adapter that supplies the suggestions:

```
// Get a reference to the AutoCompleteTextView in the layout
AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_country);
// Get the string array
String[] countries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries_array);
// Create the adapter and set it to the AutoCompleteTextView 
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = 
        new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, countries);
textView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here, a new ArrayAdapter is initialized to bind each item in the COUNTRIES string array to a TextView that exists in the simple_list_item_1 layout (this is a layout provided by Android that provides a standard appearance for text in a list).
Then assign the adapter to the AutoCompleteTextView by calling setAdapter().

Answer (score 3):

set these two fields for showing search icon on keyboard.

```
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
            android:imeActionLabel="@string/search"
```

and also if you need to perform some action on keyboard search button click then you have to add the following code.

```
    etSearch.setOnEditorActionListener((v, actionId, event) -> {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
              search();     // you can do anything
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

**KOTLIN DEVELOPERS:**

**1. XML:**

```
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/etSearch"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/sans_medium"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
            android:inputType="text" />
```

**2. Class File:**

```
etSearch.setOnEditorActionListener(object : TextView.OnEditorActionListener {
        override fun onEditorAction(v: TextView?, actionId: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                //hide Keyboard
                //do search here
                return true
            }
            return false
        }
    })
```

**NOTES:**
With `imeOptions="actionSearch"` , don't forget to add `inputType="text"` or whatever you want to set as `inputType` in your XML. Otherwise you won't be able to see search icon on keyboard open.

Comment: Works but i didn't  need input type text

Comment: @ArjunVerma Try with different devices!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the keyboard available by using the inputType for the `EditText`.

```
<EditText android:inputType="number"/>
```

[XML documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType)

...or...

```
editText.setInputType(int);
```

[Code documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setInputType%28int%29)

Answer (score 0):

Make your edittext like this.

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/s_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="Enter search" />
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/editSearch"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                android:singleLine="true"
```

must add singleLine=true in your xml 
i hope my answer help you

Answer (score 0):

set this attribute "imeOptions" in EditText view:

```
<EditText
     android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:inputType="text"
     android:hint="Enter search"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Kotlin File**

```
ed_search.setOnEditorActionListener(TextView.OnEditorActionListener { v, actionId, event ->
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
               
            }
            false
        })
```

**In XML File**

```
android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
```